# Defined Error in Visual Basic

Tags: vba

When i using this const statement,my coding work fine.

```
Const strFullName As String = "C:\Sample\Haha.txt"
```

After i change the Search.text (Textbox Name),it keep on come out the error.

```
Const strFullName As String = "C:\Sample\" & Search.Text & ".txt"
```

Compile error:

Constant expression required

Then i try create a textbox1.text = Searchbox.Text. The textbox1 shows C:\Sample\Haha.txt

Please Help,Thanks~

Comment: As the error says, when assigning the value to a constant you must use a literal value - you cannot use variables as part of an expression to calculate the value. Use a String variable instead.

Comment: besides Constant define,what else still can use?

Answer (score 1):

`Search.Text` is not a constant value - it's a run-time property and its value is not known until run-time so it cannot be assigned to a constant. You can just define your `strFullName` as a variable instead of a constant:

```
Dim strFullName As String

...
' Set strFullName at run-time
strFullName = "C:\Sample\" & Search.Text & ".txt"
```

If `Search` is a textbox, you may also want to check if it has valid input to make sure that you're not trying to form an invalid file name; for example, you can use `Len(Search.Text)` to determine the length of the text in the textbox.

Comment: Or simply check to make sure `Len(Dir(strFullName)) <> 0`, this will help ensure you don't receive a malformed file path.